# Can I append a band with different dtype to a geotiff using rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio

I have a tiff file named test.tiff. It has 4 bands of dtype uint8. Using these bands I calculated the NDVI which I would now like to save as a fifth band in the test.tiff. Only now I would like to save it as a float32.

Is there a way to do this using rasterio?
As geoTiff supports different dtypes for different bands, I guess there should be a way. but up until now I have only been able to find an example on how to do this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting this GDAL mailing list email: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-August/025657.html

> I should note that in theory the TIFF specification allows a
>   mix of sample types, but in practice this is not done in the
>   real world, and libtiff does not support it.
>
> GDAL *does* support reading mixed band types from a variety
>   of file formats, but not TIFF.  As noted, AddBand() can be used
>   in a few format cases to create mixed band types though this is
>   rarely done.

So creating a TIFF file with bands of different types seems a bit complicated.

This being said, I have found a GIS stackexchange saying that it is possible to achieve what you want with a VRT: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/207067/154376